# Show whether this algorithm produces a uniform random permutation

Tags: probability, algorithms

I am trying to solve this question from CLRS.

> Professor Armstrong suggests the following procedure for generating a
>   uniform random permutation:
>
> ```
> n = A.length
> let B[1..n] be a new array
> offset = RANDOM(1, n)
> for i = 1 to n
>     dest = i + offset
>     if dest > n
>         dest = dest - n
>     B[dest] = A[i]
> return B
> ```
>
> Show that each element A[i] has a 1/n probability of winding up in any
>   particular position in B. Then show that Professor Armstrong is
>   mistaken by showing that the resulting permutation is not uniformly
>   random.

I did a dry run, and it seems that each element A[i] winds up in any of the B[1...i] positions. For example,

when i = 1;
dest > n only if offset = n . And therefore A[1] can only wind up at B[1]

Similarly when i = 2;
dest > n only if offset = n or n - 1. And A[2] can be only placed at B[1] or B[2]

Generalizing this it seems that element A[i] can be placed in any one of the B[1...i] positions. However, this does not correlate very well with the probability of 1/n that is required in the question. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm just shifts the array to the right and feeds the overflowing elements to its left for a determined offset value. For example if the array is $123456789$ and the offset is $5$, then new array is $567891234$.

Since the offset chosen randomly from integer values between $1$ to $n$, probability for any offset value is $\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore first element in the array can take any position in the new array with equal probability which is $\frac{1}{n}$. Second element in the array can take any position in the new array with equal probability which is $\frac{1}{n}$, because second element will be in just right of the first element. And so on..

Clearly, permutation is not uniform because, for example, array containing the string $21$ can never appear.

Comment: Thank you so much! I traced the algorithm again, and it seems this is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $A[i]$ goes to position $j$, where does $A[i+1]$ go?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your hint helped me do the dry run, it seems I was making a major mistake while tracing through the algorithm.